# Javascript variables: Var a and window.a difference?

Tags: javascript, exception, window

I try to understand why?

Variable `a` is not defined and i didn't assign any value to it.
however, if i call `a`, it returns exception, but `a` is a var of window object. If i call `a` like `window.a` it returns undefined.
below screenshot is.
why so?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jcIy.png)

Comment: I would say, that’s just how JavaScript works. Accessing an undeclared variable throws an exception, accessing a non-existing property of a defined object returns `undefined`.

Comment: goddamit, it's confusing

Comment: Why is it confusing?

Answer (score 0):

In first case there is no existence of `a`.

You have neither declared `a`.

So js have no idea of `a`. When ever you are trying to access a no existence variable it will throw a [**ReferenceError**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

In second case you are trying to find a property called `a` in the [**window**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object. `window.a` will check if there is any property `a` defined on window. If it is not it will return `undefined`